# Auto switch power supply circuit

Tags: power-supply, circuit-analysis

I need 2 power supplies for a low power project, a battery and a 5v USB. I need one of them to power the circuit at a time. 2 diodes circuit (right) seems work, but Q1, will there be a leakage from lower voltage to the circuit when 5v is presented? Other than that worry, that simple circuit only draws power from higher voltage, which something is not desirable, although it's fine for my case, but I want more control. Q2, is my left circuit a better choice? Somehow I think it's problematic.

[image]

Comment: Do you need it to be automatic or not ? Can't you use jumper ?

Comment: You have two different symbols for ground in your circuit - is this intentional?

Comment: @Andy aka yes. those are same ground symbol. it's unintentional.